# Flask-SQLAlchemy query returns 0 results despite data existing in database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating my first Flask app with a SQLite database and have run into an issue where a SQLAlchemy query returns 0 results despite the data existing in the database. The goal I have is to show the result of the query on the page when loaded in a web browser. As of now it only shows `[]` on the page, which indicates to me that no records are being found despite the data's existence in the database.

For example purposes, I have a database (test_db) with one table (test_table). The table has three fields (fruit_name TEXT NOT NULL, order_amount INTEGER NOT NULL, store_id INTEGER NOT NULL). It consists of 3 records:

> fruit_name 'orange', order_amount 100, store_id 5
> fruit_name 'apple', order_amount 250, store_id 8
> fruit_name 'peach', order_amount 347, store_id 7

For the code, I begin with importing the libraries and establishing the SQLite database connection:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test_db.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

The test_db file is in the same folder as the Python file.

I then create the Python class mirroring the structure of the SQLite database:

```
class testTable(db.Model):
    _rowid_ = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fruit_name = db.Column(db.TEXT)
    order_amount = db.Column(db.INTEGER)
    store_id = db.Column(db.INTEGER)

    def __init__(self, fruit_name, order_amount, store_id):
        self.fruit_name = fruit_name
        self.order_amount = order_amount
        self.store_id = store_id
```

Since I didn't otherwise set a primary key, I used the `_rowid_` SQLite variable to use the inferred index.

Next I have the program create a page showing the output of a simple query:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    query_result = testTable.query.filter(testTable.fruit_name == "orange").all()
    return query_result
```

I read elsewhere that you need to use camel case in the name of the tables in replacement of any underscores/`_` for flask-SQLAlchemy so I am confident that part of the query is correct.

Last I end the program with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        app.run(debug=True)
```

When the page is loaded, it only shows `[]`.

My expected result would be to show the three fields for the entry with the fruit_name matching 'orange' on the page.

I tried looking online for an answer to this but was unable to find anything specific to this situation. I am not sure if the issue lies in how I made the database itself, the class object or something else I am unaware of. If any additional information or context is needed I am more than happy to share!

**Update:** I have updated the file path for the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI line per John Gordon's suggestion. A new error come up, listed below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 2213, in **call**
> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 2193, in wsgi_app
> response = self.handle_exception(e)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 2190, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1487, in full_dispatch_request
> return self.finalize_request(rv)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1506, in finalize_request
> response = self.make_response(rv)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1820, in make_response
> rv = self.json.response(rv)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py",
> line 215, in response
> f"{self.dumps(obj, **dump_args)}\n", mimetype=self.mimetype
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python
> Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py",
> line 180, in dumps
> return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Lnb2628\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json_*init*_.py",
> line 238, in dumps
> **kw).encode(obj)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Lnb2628\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py",
> line 202, in encode
> chunks = list(chunks)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Lnb2628\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py",
> line 430, in _iterencode
> yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
> File "C:\Users\Lnb2628\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py",
> line 326, in _iterencode_list
> yield from chunks
> File "C:\Users\Lnb2628\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py",
> line 439, in _iterencode
> o = _default(o)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Lnb2628\OneDrive\Documents\Python Projects\flask_practice\practice_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py",
> line 120, in _default
> raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).**name**} is not JSON serializable") TypeError: Object of type testTable is not JSON
> serializable

Comment: _The test_db file is in the same folder as the Python file_ But when you define it in the app, you use `'sqlite:///test_db.db'` which is in the root directory...

Comment: @JohnGordon , thanks for the suggestion! I redid that line to have an absolute path "sqlite:///C:\\Users\\Lnb2628\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python Projects\\flask_practice\\test_db.db" with the format following the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlite), however I now get the error "TypeError: Object of type testTable is not JSON serializable). Did I do something wrong to cause this, or is there any suggestion of how to fix this?

Comment: Please update the question to include the **whole** error message, not just the final line of it.

Comment: @JohnGordon, apologies for not doing that originally, I am still learning the ropes of how to make my posts clear on stack overflow. Thank you for bearing with me